# Result Grouping in GSA - Aggregating results based on a metadata or collection

Tags: google-search-appliance

This is a tricky question to make you understand but let me attempt it.

Today, I have 8 different portlets in my page and when global search box is triggered I fire 8 GSA queries to show each result set onto the respective portlet.

The difference between each of the GSA call are the collection names

Now I could not manage to think of a solution to replace 8 different GSA calls with one call.

Each collection has atleast 100k documents and the max result a GSA search response can give is only 1000 and 100 per request/call. So it is quite impossible for me to parse the entire XML set and programmatically group them.

I know it is a poor design to show 8 different portlets with 8 different queries so I'm not looking for help from that angle. The design is robust is an assumption. Could you think of anything creative to address this logic? Thank you very much in advance and thank you for reading my question.

Comment: There is a conflict in your statement.  If you need to have 8 portlets...then you need to have 8 portlets.  However, you are asking how to narrow down the results.  These seem to be mutually exclusive. If you have a need for 8 portlets...then you need 8 calls.  However, if you need to filter...then you should describe that need so that the community can provide some guidence.

Comment: Absolutely true. I'm new to Stackoverflow and was thinking TITLE is un-editable. My bad. I just did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Displaying 8 different result sets in 8 different portlets on a single page sounds like a fairly unpleasant user experience.

If redesigning it is an option then it sounds like a situation where faceted search would work well.

If you use [Dynamic Navigation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/admin_console_help/serve_dynamic_navigation.html) and can split your 8 collections up in to 8 facets (easy if you use [Entity Recognition](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/admin_console_help/crawl_entity_recognition.html) to tag the content based on URL patterns)you'll get a much better user experience, allowing users to drill down in to specific areas themselves rather than bombarding them with 8 different result sets.

Comment: Thank you for attempting. And thank you for agreeing with me about the the poor user experience but unfortunately i do not have a say in it. I did think of the Entity Extraction but since it will not directly substitute what we have today, I'm unable to use it. With the way it is, I could not think off or I dont think it is even possible to have one GSA call for 8 different portlets