# GSA OneBox - Internal Provider will account for the overall QPS

Tags: google-search-appliance

I think the title is self explanatory.

When I create a GSA OneBox which is powered for an internal collection. I then make a GSA search request which triggers the OneBox. Now, will the number of search request on that given second will be 1 or 2?

All i'm trying to figure out is if the OneBox which is an internal provider account for the Appliance's QPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be two while the onebox search is executing.

Comment: True. Its been documented as well. https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/2644707?hl=en#Performance

Comment: What I'm trying to understand is, the 50 QPS cap that GSA is enforcing is a hard limit? What if I have couple of onebox internal modules added to the results page and my GSA box is pretty simple and theoretically can support 60 QPS, what happens then? So before my GSA's hardware goes deficient I will be stopped by the 50 QPS cap. I know what I'm asking is little confusing :)

Comment: It's 50 concurrent threads.  If your search takes 200 ms on average then each thread can handle approximate 5 queries per second...which would 50 * 5 or 250 QPS.

Comment: That said...in doing this for about 10 years...i haven't had too many clients run up against the limit.  Secure versus Pubic is generally a bigger concern then the oneboxes.  Also, things like result clusters (/cluster) also consume those threads.  Cluster is generally the issue as it takes quite a bit of time, relatively.

Comment: I will tell why I'm worried. I have a case where we need to display 8 different portlets with 8 different collection's record with 8 different GSA queries which has only one search button. As in, when the user hits 'search', i need to fire the same query, 8 times, against different-different collections and show these 8 different results in separate portlets. I know this is a poor UI design but what they want is what they want. :) I have a separate thread for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32575332/narrow-down-search-results/32619936

Comment: Okay, so in this case, why would you use a onebox at all?   You can simply call the search search x number of times.  I have done this before again with 6 or so results without issue.  The total QPS is something that you can monitor. (Please vote up my answer if you feel it is correct)

Comment: Yes. This is exactly what I'm talking about too. Firing 6 different searches seems to be terrible design, at least from UI perspective. And in a production system, when 100 concurrent search happens, 600 search happens in the backend, which will cause quite the load. However, there is something called "Result Grouping" in  SOLR search https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping. If only this was possible in GSA my life would have been simpler :)

Comment: The idea of onebox is, every portlet of mine only shows the top few results from a particular collection. The difference between each portlet GSA query is, only the name of the collection. I though, if I use onebox-internal provider I can fool GSA and get rid of the QPS cap which is 50. Unfortunately, now I'm figuring that onebox-internal will also account for the QPS, which makes no sense in using them at all. I can very well fire 8 different queries for each portlet and chock my GSA :)

Comment: Why not put a proxy with caching so you don't make the same call twice?

Comment: Michael, Can you please elaborate your comment? I'm not quite getting it. How will caching solve my problem? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Employing a caching strategy between your portal and the GSA will potentially reduce the number of calls to the GSA.  This also would allow you to enable a proxy and reduce the queries to the GSA if necessary.