# How much concurrent users does your appliance successfully serve? - GSA QPS

Tags: google-search-appliance

Hi fellow GSA developers,

Just wanted to know, in your experience, what model of GSA are you using and how much concurrent search request load does your appliance serve successfully. And the number of total documents you have.

I know each and every environment is different but one can proportionate the data and understand the capability of the GSA Black Box.

I'm calling GSA, a black box, since you can never find out the Physical memory or any other hardware spec, nor can you change it. The only way to scale is to buy more boxes :)

Note: The question is about the GSA as a search engine and not from the portal perspective. In the sense, I'm just concerned about GSA's QPS rather than custom portal's QPS. Since custom portal, well they are custom and they are as good as it's design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on a lot of factors beyond just what model/version you have.

Are the requests part of an already authenticated session?
Are you using early or late binding?
How many authentication mechanisms are you using?
What's the flex authz rule order?
What's the permit/deny ratio for the results?

Any numbers you get in response to this question will have no real meaning to any other environment. My advice would be load test your own environment and use those results for capacity planning.

Comment: Thank you Mike for spending time on my question!!. I tend to disagree. QPS is factor which is apart from any of the factors that you mentioned. For instance, early binding or late binding will or should not affect the overall QPS, however, will have affect the overall appliance's performance. My question was solely based on the appliance, just meant for the GSA's QPS and not the performance of GSA. There is a difference in what I'm looking for. But I do agree that one has to do a load test to identify the number but I'm just looking around for peer experience details regarding QPS

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree then :) The longer each query takes to process, the fewer QPS the GSA will be able to support so the two are very tightly coupled.

Comment: @AswathNS, if you're happy with my answer could you please accept it?

Comment: I would Mike but since I'm new here and seeing around and finding out how to mark an response as Answered. Can you please me figure it out?

Comment: @AswathNS yes, the green one

Answer (score 1):

We use two GSAs with Software Version 7.2 and arranged them in a GSA^n "cluster". In the index are ca. 600,000 documents and as all of them are protected the GSA has to spend quite a lot of effort on determining which user is allowed to see which document.

Each of the two GSAs is guaranteed to perform 50 queries per second. We once did a loadtest and as some of the queries were completed in less than a second and thereby freed up the "slot" for incoming queries we were able to process 140 queries per second for a noticeable long time.

99% of our queries are completed in less than a second and as we have a rather complex structure of permissions (users with lots of group memberships) I would say this is a good result.

Like @BigMikeW already said: to get your own figures you should do a load test. Google Support provides a script which can exhaust the GSA and tell you at which QPS rate it started failing (it will simply return a http status code of 500 something).

And talking of "black box": you *are* able to find out the hardware specs. All of the GSAs I have seen so far (T3 and T4) have a dell Service tag. When you enter that tag at Dell you will find out what is inside the box. But that's pointless, because you can't modify anything of this ;-) It only will become interesting if you use a GSA model that can be repurposed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do understand that I need to do a load test myself on my appliance but I really appreciate the response. Gives some idea.

I added about 20 Onebox modules which are internal providers. My dev GSA has a QPS 5. I kept refreshing the page with 20 OneBox internal results and after a while the page started throwing 500 error code. Funny, I was the one person accessing the page and the GSA box is pretty new with hardly 100,000 documents.

Comment: @AswathNS: In sich situations you should contact support, they can look inside the box and tell you the reason. You should have mentioned the oneboxes from the beginning. And btw: on SO we show appreciation by upvoting ;-)

Comment: Nope. Its not about OneBox, hence did not mention them. I used OneBox to simulate load until I have a proper load testing script. Noted the Upvoting. Thanks guys!!

Comment: Thats the wrong type of load. Use Jmeter or the Python code available here: https://github.com/google/gsa-admin-toolkit/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

With the latest software, the GSA has 50 threads dedicated for search responses.  This means that it can be responding to 50 requests at any given time.  If the searches take on average .5 seconds, this will mean that you can average about 100 qps.

If they take longer...you'll see this be reduced.  The GSA will also queue up a few requests before responding with the appropriate http response saying the server is overloaded.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have a follow-up/related question which is there as a question in another thread. I started a new thread since I did not want to have multiple questions on the same page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641517/gsa-onebox-internal-provider-will-account-for-the-overall-qps/32854023#32854023